# How does this input filter circuit work?

Tags: power, filter

Looking through a schematic for an Analog Devices evaluation board, I got to the power input circuit but I couldn't make sense of it.

The full schematic can be viewed [here](https://ez.analog.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-wikis-components-files/00-00-00-01-10/0310.EVAL_2D00_ADV7842_2D00_7511_5F00_rev1p2_5F00_schems_5F00_20140930.pdf)

[image: Schematic of a power input for an Analog Devices evaluation board]

```
D1 - On Semi MBRS540T3G
J1 - CUI PJ1-023
C2,C3 - Murata GRM1555C1H102JA01D
L1,L2 - Laird Tech HZ1206E601R-10
F1 - Murata DLW5BSN191SQ2L
U1 - Vishay GSOT05-E3-08
C1 - Murata GRM21BR61A106KE19L
```

- Is D1 connected correctly? It doesn't seem to do anything because it is not in series between pin 1 from J1 and pin 1 from F1.
- Why are there two ground symbols in the schematic? Wouldn't the sense pin be disconnected when plugged in?
- What is the purpose of L1 and L2? And why two ferrite beads in parallel?

[image: Power input circuit from the author]

Based on the previous schematic I came up with this circuit. I guess it does the same thing but I don't know where to put both ferrite beads. They seem unnecessary if I connect the Shield and Sense pins together.

Is this schematic functionally equivalent to the original one?

Comment: please add references to the source of the  pictures into your post ... do not put them in a comment

Comment: Those two circuits are different so, what are they representing?

Comment: @Andyaka The first one is from the ADI eval board, the second one is what I understood from the first one. Can you explain how they are different?

Comment: @NeonPulse The differences are critical if you just follow the wires. Also the eval board schematic may not make much sense for a generic DC barrel jack with a switch that you have. It is possibe the eval board originally used some other connector which provided positive, return, and some sort of shield or earth wire.